What are the cut-off metal pipes next to my PVC main house drain?
Houston TX townhouse built 1981 no HOA
The picture shows the main 4" PVC drainpipe for the whole house.  This is the bottom floor, actually a crawlspace next to my garage.  There is no living space on the bottom floor, only garage and crawlspace.   The pipe goes underground into the sewer.
Next to this pipe are much smaller metal pipes.  There are two of them.  They go underground as well, but where they end up, I have no idea.   They are open to the atmosphere.  I put a screwdriver in them, and I can't move the screwdriver.
These pipes are possibly in my way of me having enough space to put in a sanitary T for a utility sink.

Does anybody have any idea what these might be, or what they might have been used for in the past?

Can I cut these pipes shorter?




enter image description here




A sink is usually about three feet(or more) above the floor.  A toilet I might see being that low, but a sink should be okay with the tee a few inches higher.

I agree with crip659, the pipes should not be in the way.   As to their origin  They may be just scrap pipes used to keep the drain pipe plumb when the foundation was poured.

I'm puzzled by how they're in the way, as they appear to be flush - or even below - the top of the 2 x 4 at the base of the wall (the bottom plate).  Are the photos deceiving, or am I looking at the wrong thing?

Mark, I have added additional pictures.  One picture shows that one of the pipes does extend above the bottom plate, not much, but it is something.  I can also cut the bottom plate if needed.  crip659, I don't need the extra space below the sink.  The other two pictures show the amount of room I have to put in the sanitary T and associated coupling.  I didn't include those pictures originally because you are not supposed to ask multiple questions in one post.  This is the first time I have done such a repair, and I wanted an option to get more space if I need it.
